# OAuth2 aws cognito authenticating without a web browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I'm working on an embedded Linux platform with Python, I do not have access to a browser. Is there an OAuth2 authentication flow that I can use without being redirected to a user login web page?  The only alternative that we are using on other OAuth2 projects is to have a separate software application authenticate and pass the tokens to the embedded device, which is kind of clunky.

Comment: did you find a solution? I have a similar situation.